# NoSuchMethodError: The method 'ref' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

there I want help, I was creating my app with flutter and firebase,
there, I want to upload images to firebase storage.
so my file

```
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

 uploadTOFirebase() async {
    final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('posts/post_$postId.jpg');
    await ref.putFile(image).whenComplete(() async {
      final url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      setState(() {
        postlink = url;
      });
      // print(postlink);
    });
  }
```

but that saw me that error

```
E/flutter (19469): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'ref' was called on null.
E/flutter (19469): Receiver: null
E/flutter (19469): Tried calling: ref("posts/post_27cfad88-62bb-4211-9e5b-0c6d1e9029be.jpg")
E/flutter (19469): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
E/flutter (19469): #1      _UploadState.uploadTOFirebase (package:instaclone/pages/upload.dart:230:48)
E/flutter (19469): #2      _UploadState.HandleSubmit (package:instaclone/pages/upload.dart:226:11)
E/flutter (19469): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19469):
```

and I'm using flutter in andoird

Answer (score 0):

Try using it like this.

```dart
final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("posts/post_$postId.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `Firebase.initializeApp()` anywhere? Without that, the Firebase SDKs won't be able to find your project on Google's servers.

See [initializing FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview#initializing-flutterfire) in the FlutterFire docs for an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
uploadTOFirebase() async {
    UploadTask storageUploadTask = FirebaseStorage.instance.putFile('posts/post_$postId.jpg');
    TaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot =
        await storageUploadTask.whenComplete(() => null);
    String url = await storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    setState((){postlink = url;});
  }
```

Try this code. Did some small changes.